# In Javascript in a function can you add a webpage if it returns false

Tags: html, function

I've got this function function

```
 checkpassword() 
{
var password = document.getElementById("passwordBox");
var passwordtext = password.value;
if(passwordtext == "reece")
{
return true;
}
alert("acsess denied!!");
                                   ← ← ← ← ←
return false;
}
```

and i want to add a web page address here if it returns false
Can you help?

Comment: So you want to redirect the user to a new page if the password is wrong? Set `window.location.href`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Answer (score 0):

To redirect a user to a new page, set the `window.location.href` attribute.

```
window.location.href = 'yourPage.html';
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot have two return statement for a function. Function execution will stop as it returns something. In this case in the else part you cannot return web page address and false independently. Have a data structure such as an object or an array having false and web addresses and return that structure.

Comment: You can absolutely have multiple `return` statements, if every `return` before the last one is not unconditional. You can still redirect to a different page and return something after that.

Comment: You can have multiple paths of execution in a function where each path can have a return statement. Once that return statement is executed the control will go to the point where the function was called. Could you please elaborate on multiple return statement in the same path of execution?

Comment: There _are_ two possible paths of execution in the OP’s code.

Comment: Exactly and in my answer I only meant the else part of execution.

Comment: I wrote the else path can't have two return statement

Comment: What are you talking about? There is no `else` part. If you mean the code after the `if`, there are no two `return` statements, there’s only one.

Comment: Correct. What I meant is if he wants to send web address and false both to the caller in after if part he can't write two return statements in after if part of the code.